# Carriage returns failing on PHP mail send

Tags: php

I know many versions of this question have been asked over the years, but none of the answers here or anywhere seem to help.

I have ticket content coming in from a single textarea on a support page.  When called from the db and echoed to the page using nl2br, all is fine.  However, when applied to a message content variable in  PHP mail, the results are different.

```
$to = 'AnEmailAddress';
$message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Message From The System</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Message: </td><td>'.$ticket_content.'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    '."\r\n";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <'.$user_email.'>' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

So far I've tried ...

```
$ticket_content = nl2br($ticket_content);
```

and putting the nl2br in the table itself ..

```
<td>Message: </td><td>'.nl2br($ticket_content).'</td>
```

I've tried preg and str replacing the \r\n's with 
's. But all to no avail, the message output is always the same.

> Hello\r\n\r\nCould you check the client has the correct colour bars
>   while you are at his appointment please?\r\n\r\nStephen

I've also tried it without a table and with a table, using just plain text and removing the top two headers.  It just will not show the line breaks whatever I do.

Comment: Are those really \r and \n characters, or just a backstroke followed by an -r or -n in plain text? Can you print the hexadecimal values of the bytes of the string? Carriage-return and linefeed should have distinct values there.

Comment: You've tagged your question as **PhpMailer** but you aren't using it. Make your life easier and use it at once! :)

Comment: Let this be yet another lesson on the theme "don't call mail(); you'll do it wrong". Use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: There's no way to say what's wrong with `$ticket_content` if we cannot see the code.

Answer (score 0):

In short, `$ticket_content` contains literal backslash+letter combinations rather than actual life feed characters. You don't give any hint on how you create the variable but you've problem misread the [manual chapter about strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), more specifically the *Escaped characters* part (emphasis mine):

> If the string is enclosed in **double-quotes** ("), PHP will interpret
>   more escape sequences for special character

Comment: If that were the case, when I used preg and str replace to try and turn them into <br />'s, would it have not changed them to literal <br />'s?  I created the variable directly from POST.  $ticket_content = $_POST['ticket'] ;

Comment: ^^ Which echos fine on the screen, so must assume its saving the newline and return data correctly?

Comment: If you type `l33t` and replace `3` with `e` you get `leet`. Is that a proof that you wrote `leet` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the string replace function as follows-

```
$ticket_content = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $ticket_content);
```

Comment: This is not even valid PHP code and you precisely omitted quotes, which are most likely the root issue. Also, how is this better that `nl2br()`?

Comment: I'll give this the plus 1 for being the closest answer.  It still didn't quite work but gave me the idea to use $ticket_content = str_replace('\r\n',"<br>",$ticket_content); Which did, and I'm sure I tried.

Comment: @Stephen No offence but I find it rather crazy to generate invalid output intentionally and then write code to fix it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I have updated my answer. I am sorry I confused it with `jquery` seeing the `$` as I was in a hurry.

Comment: @Stephen I have updated my answer. Accept the one which solved your problem so that the question can be closed.

Comment: [Right from the manual](http://php.net/nl2br): *Returns string with '<br />' or '<br>' inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).*